Finding a generator of $\tilde{H}^n(S^n)$ in Hatcher.
In Example 2.23 of Hatcher, he proved that the identity map $i_n:\Delta^n\to\Delta^n$ is a generator of $H_n(\Delta^n,\partial \Delta^n)$. Then he views the sphere $S^n$ as two $n$-simplices with their boundaries idendentified, and expresses the generator of $\tilde H_n(S^n)$ as a difference of these two n-simpices. But my question is, why not using the isomorphism $$\partial:H_{n+1}(\Delta^{n+1},\partial \Delta^{n+1})\to \tilde H_n(S^{n})$$ in Example 2.17, so that a generator of $\tilde H_n(S^{n})$ is a signed sum of faces of $\Delta^{n+1}$? Is this correct?

It looks correct and interesting, although representing it with just two simplices would be simpler in some sense.

Example 2.23 starts with "Let us find explicit cycles [...]" (emph. mine). "signed sum of faces of $\Delta^{n + 1}$" is not very explicit, is it? :) Although I do agree that treating $S^n$ as $\partial \Delta^{n + 1}$ and identifying a generator with the obvious signed sum of $n$-simplices feels a little more natural, even if it is more complicated. In any case I wouldn't read too much into it and take Ex. 2.23 more as an example of how to do computations like this.

@Ben Steffan, thanks. By signed sum of faces of $\Delta^{n+1}$, I do mean “treating $S^n$ as $\partial \Delta^{n+1}$ and identifying….” as you said. :)
